# Eloquent Javascript HELP NEWBIE

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how the recursive function is being done in this example. Problem is that he uses this technique farther down the book and I feel I need to have a grasp of what's he doing or I'm doomed. I've tried to console log the result of the function (part in quotes) to see how it changes down the line, but it doesn't give me a clear view of what's going on. Since returns often exit functions and loops, and the function is returning true at the end, I can't seem to track down how the function's suppose to work, let alone the recursive part

```js
function talksAbout(node, string) {
  if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    for (let child of node.childNodes) {
       console.log(talksAbout(child,string));
      if (talksAbout(child, string)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  } else if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    return node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1;
  }
}

console.log(talksAbout(document.body, "book"));
// → true
```

Comment: Thats not the whole function. Where is the recursion?

Comment: Maybe remembering, that the execution of the previous function continues from the next statement after the statement where recursive function was called.

Comment: @GetSet They messed up the ```, I've submitted an edit, just waiting for it to be approved.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the whole picture.. Can you give us more code?

Comment: Sorry for not adding extra code, but the book (which I'll add a link to it at the end), makes these code "snippets" that run independently and inherit properties from some outside code that runs on the server. That's one of the reasons I can't seem to follow along. I was trying to find some answers on google and I saw links to a topic called "Recursive DOM Traversal" and "Walk the DOM". I saw some examples, but I feel I'm missing some key things. Here is the link https://eloquentjavascript.net/14_dom.html

Answer (score 0):

From my best understanding of this, here's how it works, assuming the block of code is the talksAbout function.

```js
if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
```

I'm guessing this is checking if the node it's looking at is an "element" that likely contains other nodes.

```js
    for (let child of node.childNodes) {
       console.log(talksAbout(child,string));
      if (talksAbout(child, string)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
```

Here, the function seems to be iterating through the children of an element. Best I can explain it is, it's basically sending a "chain" of itself down the tree of an element, and if it finds something it's looking for, it returns true. If it doesn't find anything, it returns false.

```js
  } else if (node.nodeType == node.text_NODE) {
```

This is checking if the node it's looking at is a text node, which I'm assuming probably doesn't have any other children.

```js
     return node.nodeValue.indexOf(string) > -1;
  }
```

Here, it's checking if the string in the "string" parameter exists inside the node. If it is, it returns true, and this "true" cascades down the line of recursive calls and eventually, the entire function returns true.

If it isn't, it just kinda... does nothing, letting the other calls in the "chain" check for other stuff.

### EDIT:

It turns out, the function is massively overcomplicated. It isn't necessary to use a recursive function to search through all of the children: it's possible to just search through `node.textContent` and check for  the string you're looking for. The recursive function is equivalent to this simplified function:

```js
function talksAbout(node, string) {
   return node.textContent.indexOf(string) > -1;
}
```

It also should be noted that if the `<script>` tag containing the function call is inside the node being searched, the function will always return `true` because it'll reach into the script tag and find the function's "string" parameter.

Example:

```js
function talksAbout(node,string) {
  return node.textContent.indexOf(string) > -1; // functionally equivalent to the recursive function
}
console.log("document.body talks about 'book': " + talksAbout(document.body, "book")); // This script tag is inside document.body, so it finds the "book" string here
console.log("wrapper talks about 'bar': " + talksAbout(document.getElementById("wrapper"), "bar")); // finds string in second layer
console.log("example talks about 'bar': " + talksAbout(document.getElementById("example"), "bar")); // the word "bar" comes before the element being searched
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">foo
  <div>bar
    <div id="example">baz</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I'm practically new to programming honestly but I can wrap my head around recursion when it comes to simple n-1 argument returns. But when it comes to boolean or array recursion I feel lost. I don't seem to understand where the escape clause is defined and where the program is doing it's recursion

Comment: Small note: The function could be simplified to a non-recursive function: `function talksAbout(node,string) {return node.textContent.indexOf(string) > -1}`. It also should be noted that if you search `document.body`, you may reach into the `script` tag containing the function call, causing it to always return "true".